# getlength throwing error while using with wchar_t

Tags: c++, wchar-t, wchar, gn

I am working on a project that is written is VScode and is working properly. But when I am trying to execute the same on gn(generate ninja), this the error I am getting:-

```
error: no member named 'GetLength' in 'std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t>>'
    int sz = string.GetLength();
```

I am not sure what is wrong here. Any little hint will be highly appreciated.

Comment: `std::string` has `length()` and `size()` member functions that do the same thing. No `GetLength()` though. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size

Comment: You're using `std::wstring` for the string, but the MFC/ATL `CString` member function `GetLength()`.